# Discover custom services with drush generate

Tags: drush, services, dependency-injection

When I create a module and a custom service with `drush generate` and then create another service, also with `drush generate`, the first one is not available to inject.

What is missing to make it become available?

I'm on drupal 9.1 and drush 10.4.

The steps to reproduce

```
drush generate module
```

Given any name

```
dursh en test_module
drush cr
drush generate custom-service
drush cr
```

Given any name

```
drush generate custom-service
```

Answer dependecy injection with yes and try to find the name from the first service.

Comment: Maybe then module needs to be enabled? Or only core services can be injected? I'm gonna forward the question to Drush maintainers.

Comment: I already tested it with the module enabled, but had no luck. I tested with a generated service and the plugin manager from a generated plugin. It's a fresh installation on docksal.

Comment: Then I guess you probably need to add the code to the question to make it reproducible to tell if it's a bug or what may be wrong.

Comment: No cache flush between the first and the second service?

Comment: bwoy;-) yes edited this too. it's pretty much standard, thats why i'm wondering